# jooq binding within regexp pattern (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I have a small Java service connected to a MySQL DB which stores documents. Each document has a name, and when a document is duplicated, the new document gets the name `<previous name> (#)`. The documents table looks something like this:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A Document |
| 2 | A Document (1) |
| 3 | A Document (2) |
| 4 | Another Document |
| 5 | Another Document (1) |

I have a working MySQL query which selects a document and all of its duplicates, which I am attempting to translate into jooq.

```sql
select * from documents
where name regexp '(TITLE_GOES_HERE|TITLE_GOES_HERE \\([:digit:]+\\))$';

-- For instance, to select rows 1, 2, and 3 of the above table,
-- I would replace `TITLE_GOES_HERE` with `A Document`, resulting
-- in the following MySQL query:
select * from documents
where name regexp '(A Document|A Document \\([:digit:]+\\))$';
```

> **Note:** If you would like a working regex tester, you can find it [here](https://regex101.com/r/EqhhEe/1). It's slightly different than the MySQL version, but it suffices for demonstration purposes.

In order for this query to work programmatically, I have to replace "TITLE_GOES_HERE" in the regular expression with the name of the document for which I want to find. However, that throws an unexpected error in jooq.

```java
public List<Document> getOriginalAndDuplicates(String docName) {
  SelectQuery<DocumentRecord> select = getDSLContext().selectQuery(DOCUMENT);

  select.addCondition(
    DSL.condition(
      DSL.field(
        // Binding for both the document AND the name
        // Notice that the name binding is inside the regular expression
        "{0} regexp '({1} \\\\([:digit:]+\\\\))'",
        Boolean.class,
        DOCUMENT.NAME,
        docName)));

  Result<DocumentRecord> records = select.fetch();
  List<Document> docs = records.stream().map(documentConverter::convertTo).toList();
  return docs;
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select document.id, document.name from document where (document.name regexp '({1} \\([:digit:]+\\))')]; Syntax error in regular expression on line 1, character 2.
    at org.jooq_3.14.16.MYSQL.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2903)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:757)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:389)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error in regular expression on line 1, character 2.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:555)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:339)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute(ClientPreparedStatement.java:354)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:214)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.executeStatementAndGetFirstResultSet(Tools.java:4217)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:283)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:375)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

The error is occurring because the first binding (`{1}`) is not being replaced with the document name.

Has anyone ever encountered anything like this?

> **Additional info:** When I replace the `{1}` with a hardcoded value, such as `A Document`, the query succeeds without any problems. It only causes problems when I try to bind the `{1}` to a variable value.

Comment: What is the output you actually want here?

Comment: A java `List<Document>` containing the following elements:

`Document[1, "A Document]`, `Document[2, "A Document (1)"]`, `Document[3, "A Document (2)"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why your plain SQL template didn't work

A jOOQ [plain SQL template](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) will not make any substitutions in string literals or comments, and other things. As per the documentation:

> ### Parsing rules
>
> When processing these plain SQL templates, a mini parser is run that handles things like
>
> - String literals
> - Quoted names
> - Comments
> - JDBC escape sequences
> - Indexed (?) or named (:identifier) bind variable placeholders
>
> The above are recognised by the templating engine and contents inside of them are ignored when replacing numbered placeholders and/or bind variables.

Your template has to be written like this:

```java
DSL.field(
    "{0} regexp concat('(', {1}, '\\\\([:digit:]+\\\\))'",
    Boolean.class,
    DOCUMENT.NAME,
    docName
)
```

Note the number of `\\` needed depends on the `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` setting, which you can also configure in jOOQ. jOOQ handles this automatically if you're not using a plain SQL template.

#### Using jOOQ API instead

But why bother using a template? jOOQ has native support for this operator using [`Field.likeRegex()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#likeRegex(org.jooq.Field)):

```java
DOCUMENT.NAME.likeRegex(concat(val("("), val(docName), val("\\([:digit:]+\\))")))
```

Comment: the solution you posted works, except that it doesn't escape special characters. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing that escapes any special characters that may occur in the document name?

Comment: Found a solution. I just added `\\Q` and `\\E` before and after the injected string, and MySQL's regex interprets the entire sequence as string literals.

Comment: @teuber789: That's an interesting detail, indeed. Perhaps almost worth an independent question only about that? Surely, other jOOQ users might have the same problem. You could ask *and* answer your own question, as is encouraged by Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/